# Is Typecasting a normal pointer to a unique_ptr a bad practice?

Tags: c++, c++11

I implemented a singly linked list using `unique_ptr` with mix of normal pointers.

I have this code:

```
template<typename B>
void linkedlist<B>::addNode(B x){
  node * n = new node;                      //initialize new node
  n->x = x;
  n->next = nullptr;                        //smart pointer

  if(head == nullptr){                      //if the list is empty
    head = (unique_ptr<node>)n;             //cast the normal pointer to a unique pointer

  }else{                                    //if there is an existing link
    current = head.get();                   //get the address that is being
                                            //pointed by the unique_ptr head


    while(current->next != nullptr)         //loop until the end then stop
      current = (current->next).get();

    current->next = (unique_ptr<node>) n;   //connect the new node to the  last node
  }
}
```

I heard that it's a bad practice, if so then can someone tell me why? Suggestions and tips for proper practices will also be appreciated.

Comment: Use directly `auto n = std::make_unique<node>();` and `head = std::move(n);` to avoid all your cast.

Comment: I see, let me try it.

Comment: Why is your indentation such a mess? What prevented you from correcting that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the cast syntax is slightly strange, it's exactly equivalent to the more conventional

```
unique_ptr<node>(n)
```

and so isn't itself bad practice. What is bad practice is to have the raw pointer hanging around at all, with a danger that it might leak if there is a code path that doesn't either delete it or transfer it to a smart pointer.

You should start with

```
unique_ptr<node> n(new node);
```

and transfer ownership by moving from it

```
head = std::move(n);
```

Comment: So i will have to change node * n = new node;  to   unique_ptr<node> n(new node);?

Comment: @CarloBrew: You should, yes. Then you can be sure it won't leak, without having to trace all the code paths to make sure.

Comment: I converted everything to what you said and they still worked as intended. Thanks for the answer and clarification!

Answer (score 0):

In your case it may not be an issue but casting existing raw pointers to unique_ptrs is a bit of a bad practice mainly due to the semantics involved. Unique_ptr will run a deleter when goes out of scope.

Consider the following

```
int ptr_method(int * i) {
    auto a = (unique_ptr<int>)i;
    return *a.get();
}

int main() {
    int i = 10;
    ptr_method(&i);
}
```

What happens to `i` when `ptr_method` returns ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Of the question, no, it's more of a comment on the practice of casting raw pointers to unique_ptr.

Comment: I tried your code, i printed it and it still shows as 10.

Comment: @CarloBrew where did you put your print ? You should get an error (invalid pointer) when you run it.

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou  cout<<ptr_method(&i)<<endl;

Comment: @CarloBrew and after that you must be getting an error (it should print 10, and then an error)

Comment: @CarloBrew, it may be suppressing it but the snippet is intended to show that after the return, the deleter is invoked. It can't *actually* free *i so it throws an invalid pointer error. The main point is that you should be a bit careful when mixing raw pointers with unique_ptrs as there is an implied deletion when the unique_ptr goes out of scope that may be unexpected.

Comment: What I'm getting, for posterity, is *** Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff7c900a9c ***
[1]    9697 abort      ./a.out

Comment: Anyway i get your point , ill try to avoid casting if possible. Thank you , that was helpful.

Comment: _"after that you must be getting an error"_ No, the results of UB are completely unpredictable.